# Integration of the function $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have some troubles with the next integral:

$$\displaystyle\int_{2}^{8}\displaystyle\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$

Is there a way to calculate this integral without using software? I don't have idea how can I do it.

This exercise comes of the calculation of $$\int_{2}^{8}\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}}^{2}e^{y}\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}}\,dxdy$$

But, doesn't matter if I interchange the order of integraton or not, because in any way, the previous integral appears (in one case, appears with other limits of integration).

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with the special function $\rm{erfi}(\cdot)$ given in terms of the error function:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions

Comment: Also, what happens if you try making it look like a Lognormal distribution, but instead of x you put $\sqrt{x}$ ?

Comment: @OlivierOloa That function is not familiar to me. Then, are there no ways to calculate that integral without involving the error function?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez One may use the expansion $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ then integrate termwise, or one may use some standard numerical integrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the integration with respect to $x$ first, you should obtain:
$$\int_2^8\left(\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}}^2e^y\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}~dx\right)~dy=\int_2^8 e^y\cdot \left(\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{y}}-\frac{2}{3}\right)~dy=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}\int_2^8 \frac{e^y}{\sqrt{y}}~dy-\frac{2}{3}\int_2^8 e^y~dy$$
I added this so that you could verify if you are doing everything correctly so far. Now, let's move to your request:

---

You asked how we can evaluate the following definite integral **without** the use of software:
$$\int_2^8 \frac{e^y}{\sqrt{y}}~dy \tag{1}$$

> One can express it in terms of the [Imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function) $\operatorname*{erfi}(x)$. It is defined as:
>
> $$\operatorname*{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{t^2}~dt \tag{2}$$

Now, here comes the trick. We can substitute the following into $(1)$:
$$y=u^2 \iff dy=2u~du$$
This gives:
$$\int_2^8 \frac{e^y}{\sqrt{y}}~dy=\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{8}} \frac{e^{u^2}}{u}\cdot 2u~du=2\cdot \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}} e^{u^2}~du \tag{3}$$
From the definition in $(2)$, we can deduce that:
$$\int e^{x^2}~dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname*{erfi}(x)+C$$
Using this fact, we know that:
$$2\cdot \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}} e^{u^2}~du=2\cdot \left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname*{erfi}(u)\right]_{\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\pi}\cdot [\operatorname*{erfi}(u)]_{\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\pi}\left(\operatorname*{erfi}(2\sqrt{2})-\operatorname*{erfi}(\sqrt{2})\right)$$
Hence:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_2^8 \frac{e^y}{\sqrt{y}}~dy=\sqrt{\pi}\left(\operatorname*{erfi}(2\sqrt{2})-\operatorname*{erfi}(\sqrt{2})\right)\approx 1133.22501}$$
I checked [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+2+to+8:+e%5Ex%2Fsqrt(x)) just to be sure that my answer is correct. Use this result to find the value of the double integral.